# Excel: How to keep cells together when sorting on a different column

Tags: excel

I have the following excel table(sample), with four columns. 
I want to sort data on Name, while doing that I want to keep the cells from the Assets column together and reposition along with the with the Name. Is it possible? I can't merge the cells.

[image]

please help if there is a way.
many thanks. 
M

Comment: You can't do that. Ranges in Excel must be sorted equal. I mean, you cannot keep the assets together as you wish. Try copying name, age and net worh in each cell, and then resume your data with Pivot Tables, and then try to order there.

Comment: You could maybe try to add a value to every Cell of column "Name". This way, if you sort on name and expand the sort range, the data in "Assets" should remain "grouped".

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answers, Pivot table makes sense. I will try.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `Name` is in A1, in say F2 and copied down to suit:

```
=IF(A2="",F1,A2)
```

then sort A2:F9 on ColumnF.